# How can I display an operating-system environment variable from within Excel?

Tags: windows, excel, ms-office

I have an application written in Excel plus a bunch of C++ / Python addins.

The location of the various config files used by the addins is determined at startup time by a number of environment variables. I'd like to debug a problem related to these environment variables by the most direct possible means: Can I simply type in an Excel formula which will cause an environment variable to display in the worksheet?

Let me give you an example:

I have an environment variable called "**MYADDIN_XML_CONFIG**" which contains the path to an XML file used by the MyAddin component. If this environment variable is set incorrectly then MyAddin will fail to run. I'd like to have a single simple function which takes the string "**MYADDIN_XML_CONFIG**" as an argument and returns the value of the env-var if it is set. If the environment variable is not set it should return a NONE or some kind of error code.

Can this be done?

FYI, MS Excel 2003 on Windows XP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know any built-in Excel formula that does this, but you can create a public function in a VBA module:

```
Public Function Env(Value As Variant) As String
    Env = Environ(Value)
End Function
```

then use this as a user-defined formula in a worksheet, e.g.

```
=Env("COMPUTERNAME")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the VBA function `Environ("MYADDIN_XML_CONFIG")`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the accepted solution won't work if your environment variable changes its value (even if you reopen the Excel workbook, the value of the cell won't change). If you want to have it updated more often you should update cell's value on some event,

e.g. Worksheet_Activate (code should be placed in VBAProject->Microsoft Excel Objects->Sheet which should be observed):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate() 
    Range("a1") = Environ("SOME_ENV_VARIABLE")
End Sub
```

or Workbook_Open (code should be placed in VBAProject->Microsoft Excel Objects->ThisWorkbook):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Range("a1") = Environ("SOME_ENV_VARIABLE")
End Sub
```